# Trying to create login page using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I've been working on a website login, and so far, I have the database and register page set up, but I'm trying to work on a Login page. I've been trying to retrieve data from the Database's  Table. I was successfull at doing so on my register page to make sure there aren't multiple usernames of the same name, so I copied some of the code and pasted it onto this page. The problem: it returns blank. Please help... ._.
`   
    
        
        KHS SiteSpace

```
    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="./IMAGES/khslogo2.png" style="margin-left:4;float:left;" width="100" hieght="100"></a>
        <b>KHS<span id="name">SiteSpace</span></a>
            <!--img src="./IMAGES/Menu.png" style="float:right;margin-right:6;" height="100" width="90"-->
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p id="subTitle">Login</p>
            <div style="float:left;height:30%;">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" id="register"><br>
                    Username:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
                    Password:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="pass">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;width:50%;border-style:none none none solid; border-color:222222;border-width:4;height:30%;">
            <p style="margin-left:20;font-size:20;">Output:</p>
            <p style="margin-left:20;padding-bottom:15;">
                <?php

                error_reporting(0);
                @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
                session_start();
                $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "shanedrgn", "getting321", "Users");
                if (!$conn) {die("Failure to connect");}
                $name = trim($_POST['name']);
                $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);

                if (empty($name) or empty($pass)) {echo "Empty Fields";} else {
                $name = trim($_POST['name']);
                $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);

                    echo "Check: The fields arent empty...";#OUTPUT
                    echo "Testing Variables...";#OUTPUT

                    //Error Trapping
                    $sql = "SELECT Username FROM Users where Username = '$name'";
                    $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    if($record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data)) {
                        $nameTrap = $record['Username'];
                    }
                    $sql = "SELECT Address FROM Users where Address = '$address'";
                    $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    if($record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data)) {
                        $ipTrap = $record['Address'];
                    }


                    if ($nameTrap == $name) {

                        echo "Check: Username Exists...";

                        if ($passTrap == $pass) {
                            echo "Password is correct!";
                            $_SESSION['User'] = $name;
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users where Username = '$name'";
                            $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            $record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data);
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['id'] = $record['id'];
                            echo "<script>alert('You have successfully logged in!')</script>";
                            sleep(4);
                            header("Location: ./index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
                            exit();
                        } else { echo "Password Invalid";}

                    } else {echo "That username doesn't exist!";echo $name.";;";echo $nameTrap;}
                }

                ?>
                </p></div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>`
```

EDIT: Added missing code

Comment: Set all of your error reporting to `'1'`

Comment: Neither `$nameTrap` nor `$passTrap` are defined.

Comment: I accidentally deleted that... I was testing to see what worked. I just basically copied ad pasted what I has at the moment. Sorry, and thankyou ver much for actually doing something to help :)

Comment: Code: 
`$sql = "SELECT Username FROM Users where Username = '$name'";
      $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if($record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data)) {
       $nameTrap = $record['Username'];
      }
      $sql = "SELECT Address FROM Users where Address = '$address'";
      $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if($record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data)) {
       $ipTrap = $record['Address'];
      }`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
echo "<script>alert('You have successfully logged in!')</script>";
sleep(4);
header("Location: ./index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
```

I understand, what you try, but it can't work. You can't set an Header after sending Body-Content - what you do using echo.

You should use JavaScript for your redirect, after the 4 second timeout. Use `setTimeout` and `window.location`.

Comment: Thank you, you're a great guy for answering, but I screwed up and left a lot of code out. The sleep(4) is from when I though it worked, but instead worked because it accepted everything. The javascript works fine though :)

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT Username FROM Users where Username = '$name'";
      $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if($record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data)) {
       $nameTrap = $record['Username'];
      }
      $sql = "SELECT Address FROM Users where Address = '$address'";
      $Data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if($record=mysqli_fetch_array($Data)) {
       $ipTrap = $record['Address'];
      } `